# Sass custom importer

Tags: ruby, sass

I have a piece of ruby code for compiling .scss code. I am trying to build a custom importer to load files from DB.

Here is my ruby code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sass'
require 'sass/plugin'
require './eptimporter'  # my custom importer( code below )

Sass::Plugin.options[:load_paths] ||= []
Sass::Plugin.options[:load_paths] << Sass::Importers::Eptimporter.new("dummy")

puts Sass::Plugin.options[:load_paths]
puts Sass.compile_file("sass/sass.scss")  # scss file (code below)
```

Here is my importer:

```
module Sass
  module Importers
    class Eptimporter < Base

      attr_accessor :root

      def initialize(root)
        @root = root
      end

      # @see Base#find_relative
      def find_relative(name, base, options)
        nil
      end

      # @see Base#find
      def find(name, options)
        options[:syntax] = ":scss"
        options[:filename] = name
        options[:importer] = self
        Sass::Engine.new("p { color :blue; }", options)
      end

      # @see Base#mtime
      def mtime(name, options)
        Time.now
      end

      # @see Base#key
      def key(name, options)
        [self.class.name , name]
      end

      # @see Base#to_s
      def to_s
        @root
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And finally my scss file:

```
@import "dummy.scss";
p { 
  color: red; 
  span { text-transform: uppercase; }
}
```

The custom importer just returns a static CSS code `p { color :blue; }` no matter what the import string is. I do get a `File to import not found or unreadable: dummy.scss. (Sass::SyntaxError)` error. What can cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your Importer is being registered?
Try registering like this:
Sass.load_paths << Sass::Importers::Eptimporter.new('dummy')

You might also find a problem in the options[:syntax]. It should be :scss instead of ":scss"

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash to pass your options to compile_file.

```
load_paths = Sass::Plugin.options[:load_paths] || []
load_paths << Sass::Importers::Eptimporter.new("dummy")

Sass.compile_file("sass/sass.scss", {:load_paths => load_paths})
```

or

```
Sass.compile_file("sass/sass.scss", {:importer => Sass::Importers::Eptimporter.new("dummy")})
```